# What is the minimum number of steps for two elements of a Lie algebra to generate the whole Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, lie-algebras

Consider a compact, connected and simply connected Lie Group $G$, and two elements in the corresponding Lie algebra $X$ and $Y$. By successive action of exponential map you can get the following element in the Lie group
$$e^{\alpha_1 X}e^{\alpha_2 Y}...e^{\alpha_{n-1} X}e^{\alpha_n Y} \in G.  $$
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ can generate the whole Lie algebra, then the whole Lie group $G$ can be generated.

For example, consider $SU(2)$ and $X=i\sigma_x, Y=i\sigma_y$ (where $\sigma$ are Pauli matrices), then they can generate the whole $SU(2)$ by the famous parametrization of Euler angles.

The question is: what is the minimum number of $n$ for a general Lie group $G$? For example, for a $SU(2)$, the number is 3.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Wait, with your numbering Euler angles give the minimum $n$ for $\textrm{SO}(3)$ as two, not three: $A$ $=$ $e^{\psi J_3}e^{\theta J_1}e^{\phi J_3}$ $=$ $e^{\alpha_1 J_3}e^{\beta_1 J_1}e^{\alpha_2 J_3}$.

Comment: I understand the question as: what is the minimal $n$ such that $G$ is setwise product of $n$ 1-parameter subgroups? Clearly $\dim(G)$ is a lower bound.

Comment: Thank you for your correction! Yes, I have changed the numbering so that it will cause no confusion, and YCor's comment is perfectly correct

Comment: Actually no, I don't think it's an equivalent restatement...

Comment: Why? Do you mean that the order of $X$ and $Y$ will cause trouble

Comment: Sorry, but the $X$ and $Y$ are fixed, they are some pre-determined elements in the Lie algebra

Comment: @WeichengYe Did you finally find an answer to your question?

Comment: You may be interested in results from quantum algorithms on the quantum approximate optimization algorithm, which similar to the product you wrote, is a product of "driving (ZZ)" and "mixing ( X)" terms. The difficulty in this problem is determining the phase angles. https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.15645